# Can I change the position of the camera during an animation?

Tags: animation, camera

How can I change the position of the camera during an animation?

Comment: (1) Have you tried setting keyframes on different frames for the camera location? (2) I am seeing a lot of tags. Could you please reconsider, which tags are actually valid? It sound the animation tag should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how can I change the position of the camera while animating another object then you can simply select the camera and move it around inset key frame and step some key frames and repeat.
I hope this helps you.